# How to stop parameters from updating in Torch?

Tags: python, pytorch

I am working on a project where I wrote my own Pytorch model. The model takes input of multiple individuals and returns output for all of the individuals at the the same time. The output together gives a mean squared error loss. In the weight updating step, I want the parameters related to one of the individuals to be frozen because there are nan values in the specific individual's data. I got stuck on this issue.
Your input would be highly appreciated.

My attempt till now:

```
    freeze_index = 1

    for (covariates, targets) in data_iter:

        # forward pass
        predictions = forward_pass(covariates, targets, encoder, decoder, device)
     
        # set decoder.decoder_list[nan_indices], requires_grad = False
        false_params = _freeze_params(decoder, freeze_index)

        # calculate loss
        loss = calculate_loss(targets, predictions, encoder, decoder, quantile_levels, device)
        # --> loss gives a non nan value in the first iteration and a nan value in the next iteration (after the weight update step).
        # backward pass
        encoder_optimizer.zero_grad()
        decoder_optimizer.zero_grad()
        
        # ---> parameters are floats
        loss.backward()
        
        # set partial loss to zero for country with nan values
        encoder_optimizer.step()
        decoder_optimizer.step()

        # ---> all parameters equal nan 

        _unfreeze_params(false_params)

        # update epoch loss
        epoch_loss_sum += loss.item()
```

My guess is that something goes wrong in the loss.backward(). I think this has to do with the "leaves" tied to the loss. I am a bit puzzled about how the backward() function works under the hood and how I can manipulate it. I think that the backward function still makes use of all the data (including the nan valued data of the excluded individual). Maybe this causes the error. But since the loss gives a non nan number in the first iteration, I would think the backward function should work properly.